# System Requirements for android app development using xamarin and visual studio 2015 community

Tags: xamarin.android

I have windows 7 installed in my computer. I am trying to develop android application using visual studio community 2015 and xamarin.
But I am Getting an error while deploying.
I want to Know system requirements for developing android aaplication using visual studio 2015 community and [xamarin](/questions/tagged/xamarin).

Error while deploying is as below:-

```
Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]
1> at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
1> at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass90_0.b__0(Task`1 t)
```

Comment: Please suggest me as soon as possible....

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you're trying to install an application on a device which uses an *architecture* that isn't supported by a part of the application.

If you're using a very obscure device, Xamarin bundles several native libraries in every Xamarin.Android app and it's possible that one of those isn't compatible with your device.

Another possiblity is that you're using an emulator that uses "Intel" architecture. This might not be compatible with libraries designed for devices using the "ARM" architecture, most commonly found in phones and tablets. If that's the case, try using a different emulator.